# XML layout tutorials

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an application for a bank for a project.

I want the layout of the application to look like this:

[image]

I want to know how to do the views, and the lines separating each view.

If you have a tutorial on how to do this or XML codes or tips, would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried views , working on linear layout , but did not look anything like this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the accepted answer. You can also check out [Android's Preference Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) or [this example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many implementations of this, but https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders is one (you can turn of the sticky headers if you just want the sections). You could also use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge from our very own @CommonsWare, I believe ;)